# Incremental MySQL restore using binlogs

Tags: mysql, backup, restore, mysqlbinlog

I've tried to restore a MySQL database using incremental binlogs and mysqlbinlog tool but I received the following message:

ERROR 1666 (HY000) at line 30: Cannot execute statement: impossible to write to binary log since statement is in row format and BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT.

BINLOG_FORMAT parameter in my database is set to ROW, but is there a way to restore binglog with this parameter in ROW?

Comment: Are you sure the database BINLOG_FORMAT is ROW? Could you post MySQL version and my.cnf?

Answer (score 2):

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'binlog_format';
```

I believe you will find the server will tell you that it is configured for `STATEMENT` since there's not another good reason why you'd get this error.

The error message is referring to the server where you're trying to restore the files as currently configured, not the format the server may have been in when the log was created.

MySQL has two logging formats for replication, `ROW`, which logs the actual changes made to individual rows, and `STATEMENT`, which logs the queries that made the changes.  The `MIXED` format isn't a different format, but instead is a configuration setting that allows the server to select the format for each query based on internal rules.

When a server has binary logging enabled and executing queries from an incoming binlog, it has to write the queries to its own binlog, but it doesn't just copy the incoming log entry into the outgoing log... if the server is configured for `ROW`, it will always translate incoming `STATEMENT` events into `ROW` events.  If it is configured for `MIXED`, then it *may* log incoming `STATEMENT` events as outgoing `STATEMENT` events or it may log them as `ROW`... but if it is configured for `STATEMENT` then it is unable to log incoming `ROW` events, and the error you're seeing would be what is returned.

```
 -- server receives  -- server global   -- server writes          
 -- incoming event   -- binlog_format   -- outgoing event

    STATEMENT           STATEMENT          STATEMENT
    STATEMENT           MIXED              STATEMENT or ROW
    STATEMENT           ROW                ROW
    ROW                 STATEMENT          XXX NOT SUPPORTED XXX
    ROW                 MIXED              ROW
    ROW                 ROW                ROW
```

If `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'binlog_format';` really does say `ROW` I'll be surprised, but if not, then your fix should be this:

```
SET GLOBAL BINLOG_FORMAT = 'ROW';
```

Comment: +1 This answer should be in mysql official doc.  I spend hours to find a definitive answer for binlog_format.